# toggle custom image in a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uibarbuttonitem

I've been breaking my head for the past two days searching and trying some of my own solutions. I placed a UIBarButtonItem through IB with an image in the top bar to act as a mute/unmute button . Everything works except the image doesn't change. I used the following code and it compiles but no change

```
if( mute == YES ) {
    UIImage *unmuteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio-on.png"];
    [self.muteButton setImage:unmuteImage];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"muteKey"];
}
else {
    UIImage *muteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio-off.png"];
    [self.muteButton setImage:muteImage];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"muteKey"];
}
```

Comment: Have yoy tried cleaning the build? Make sure the app is not running, then press SHIFT-CMD-K.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've checked that self.muteButton is not nil? You've definitely connected it in Interface Builder?

Comment: im running it on my ipod touch. I have a NSLog that tells me what bool's state is every time i hit the button and it's fine. The sound will go on or off as it should too. Only problem is the icon always stays the same. Its the [self.muteButton setImage:muteImage] that isnt working even though it compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out...only took a couple of days but I've been too busy to post up a solution. We'll I finally got time and am happy to post my solution. I had a hunch that this would'nt work unless it was done 100% programmatically, and I was right. Here's the final solution to my problem:

```
if(mute == YES)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio-off.png"];
    UIButton *myMuteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myMuteButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );    
    [myMuteButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myMuteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mute) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    UIBarButtonItem *myMuteBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myMuteButton];   
    navBar.leftBarButtonItem = myMuteBarButtonItem;
    [myMuteBarButtonItem release];
}
else
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio-on.png"];
    UIButton *myUnmuteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myUnmuteButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );    
    [myUnmuteButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myUnmuteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mute) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    UIBarButtonItem *myUnmuteBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myUnmuteButton];
    navBar.leftBarButtonItem = myUnmuteBarButtonItem;
    [myUnmuteBarButtonItem release];
}
```

the good news is I finally finished my app and submitted it to the app store. Hopefully everything will go smooth and am looking forward to it!

Comment: Nice solution - you could also refine it slightly by just using one UIButton and setting two images; one for the selected state and one for the normal state.  Then, upon pressing your mute button, you simply change the button state, i.e. [myButton setSelected:YES];

Comment: I tried using this solution, but for some reason my target is never called when pressing the button. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Swift,

I set mine around an instance var, and used that to toggle my switch. I also had 3 buttons in my nav bar.

```
private var activeStaff:Staff? {
    didSet {
        let image = (activeStaff == nil) ? UIImage(named: "active")! : UIImage(named: "notActive")!
        let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "activePressed:")

        if navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.count == 3 {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.removeAtIndex(0)
        }

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.insert(button, atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```